# Setting up roaming profiles

Tags: user-profile, home-server

I am trying to set up roaming profiles on Ubuntu Server. My goal is to be able to log on to the server from any computer in my house running Ubuntu, and have the profile for the user I logged in as loaded onto that computer. What is the easiest way to accomplish this?

Comment: I cannot get your meaning for roaming? Could you explain that better? Do you have wifi or what type of roaming you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest approach would be using same user and group id and username in all of the computers (and server)