# How do I set up a Roaming Profile?

Tags: installation

I am new to Ubuntu and recently started working, i wanted to set a Roaming Profile on Ubuntu Server. So user can login in from any computer and there worked can be saved directly to the Server.

Any help suggestion wou

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting up roaming profiles](http://askubuntu.com/questions/121515/setting-up-roaming-profiles)

Answer (score 3):

One way is to install LDAP and possibly Kerberos. Kerberos will let you control the shared NFS directories with better security. If you add Samba, you can use the roaming profiles on Windows machines too.

You can start looking at Ubuntu Server Help Center for [LDAP/Kerberos authentication](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/network-authentication.html) and for [NFS4 with Kerberos](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NFSv4Howto). I have this working perfectly since 2007.

Another way is to use [Samba4](http://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Samba4) but afaik it is still in RC release. I never used it but people seems to have it working already. Maybe it is worth to give it a look to see where they are as you are starting a new install.

---

UPDATE

In your comment you said you are using mysql to authenticate and you want to have roaming home directories so a possible way to do this is to export the home directories from a file server with NFS and mount them on each machine.

I think the way to change the place of the home directoriy (if needed so you can leave the local users on /home and the network users on /nethome for example) is to use a field in MySQL like (if you didn't change nss-mysql conf file):

```
homedir varchar(32) DEFAULT '/bin/sh' NOT NULL
```

I never did that with MySQL authentication but it should work like with LDAP.

When you do this, I think it is better to use NFS with Kerberos authentication for many reasons but mainly because with it you can avoid a local root to su to any network user and access the other user home directory.

Comment: Obs: to administer the openLDAP server, I prefer to use Apache Directory Studio (http://directory.apache.org/studio) instead of the scripts in Ubuntu help page but this depends on the quantity of users because I think that for a lot of frequent changes, the scripts may be easier to use.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help :) I will look into it

Comment: Hello Everyone, referring to my problem again currently we already have MySQL Authentication and Name Server Switch which allow the file to transfer over the network. But the problem is i want to store the user(client (Ubuntu) platform)on the server so they can access it from any machine.

Comment: updated answer on this point